# i18n PHP vs AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, internationalization

I have a small question about i18n, I have a test website in php and AngularJS, and I would apply across all i18n page of this website,
I hesitate between php and angularjs i18n translation, I would like to have your opinion,

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would go with PHP.
PHP uses ICU for internationalization, which means that it supports hundreds of locales, and doe it well.
AngularJS, being client side, has severe size limitations, and in general the i18n support is not that good. And some things not even possible (for instance proper sorting)

Note: by "i18n" I understand things like number / currency / date / time formatting, sorting, MessageFormat that handles correctly things like plurals.